# What am I doing wrong with Out-File?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, powershell-3.0

I cannot get this command to output to text file. I am trying to use the out-file command.

```
#Trim up the URL
$data = get-content C:\Dell\Temp\urlhausCopyDL.txt
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $items = $_.split(":")
    write-host  (-join('http:',$items[1])) | Out-File "C:\Dell\Temp\Formulated.txt" -Append
}
```

It creates the file but it is blank.

It splits the URL and removes whatever is after the second : as we don't need it.

It outputs to Console great, but I just cant get it to write to a file!! :(

```
A snippet of urlhauscopyDL is here for you:
http://115.55.196.162:57955/bin.sh
http://182.240.54.209:60488/bin.sh
http://176.231.66.63:49310/.i
```

Thankyou For your help team  :)

Comment: Well `Write-Host` writes to the console so you don't need it there. It's only meant for that. Just remove `Write-Host` and it will be fine, also `| Out-File..` can go after closing the loop instead of inside

Comment: YES! This worked perfectly - Thankyou!!

#Trim up the URL
$data = get-content C:\Dell\Temp\urlhausCopyDL.txt
$data | ForEach-Object {
  $items = $_.split(":")
 (-join('http:',$items[1])) 
 
 } | Out-File "C:\Dell\Temp\ParsedA.txt" -Append

Comment: @barge77, unless you need to append to the content of a preexisting file, don't use `-Append`. The two linked duplicates address address the two problematic aspects of your approach, respectively.